# How to best navigate around and land at KPAO (Palo Alto, CA)?

Tags: airport, flight-planning, sfo

Flying VFR into KPAO from the South for the first time in a Cherokee. Any advice on the best way to navigate KSJC and the SFO Bravo?  Thanks.

Comment: I asked [a meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4027/62) about this

Answer (score 5):

If you’re coming in VFR from the south, I’d recommend skirting around the San Jose Class C and Moffet’s Class D by flying over the Lexington Reservoir, over Los Gatos and Saratoga and staying just north of the foothills of Palo Alto.  Flown at lower altitudes, you’ll avoid KSFO’s Class B airspace.  Just be aware there’s a lot of GA VFR traffic down in the weeds in that area.  Also be aware of TFRs over Stanford, should they be hosting football games at their stadium.   Typically arrivals and departures from the west are given the Stadium visual arrivals, routing them to Stanford Stadium, thence to a downwind or base entry at KPAO.  Arrivals and departures to the north are given the Bridge visual arrival and departure to the Dumbarton Bridge then entry into KPAO pattern.  Remember as well that “Kung Pao” only has a 2400 ft runway, so be on the ball with you short field ops.  There is extensive flight training going on at that airport and the pattern can be extremely busy on good weather days.  Have a taxi diagram ready to go and be aware of taxi routing via the east loop Taxiway Golf - terminal side - or the west loop taxiway Golf - hanger side.